# accessing value of dictionary using while loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary

May I know best solution for accessing values of dictionary using while loop not with for each because i have already a while so that i can reduce no of lines in my program what i did so far is

```
while (da.Read())
 {
    Dictionary<string, decimal> d = b.findclosingbalanceofledger(da["LeId"].ToString());
    foreach (var pair in d)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(pair.Key);
      MessageBox.Show(pair.Value.ToString());
     }
  }
```

what i am trying to do is

```
 while (da.Read())
 {
    Dictionary<string, decimal> d = b.findclosingbalanceofledger(da["LeId"].ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(pair.Key);
    MessageBox.Show(pair.Value.ToString());
  }
```

b.findclosingbalanceofledger(id)
has following code

```
public Dictionary<string,decimal> findclosingbalanceofledger(string id)
        {
            decimal totalcredit = 0;
            decimal totaldebit = 0;
            decimal closingbalance =0;
            string  closingbalancetype;
            Dictionary<string, decimal> closingbalanceofledger = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
           con.Open();
           string sql = @"select sum(Amount) as total,vocherType from Voucher where LedId=@LedId and vocherType=@Payment group by vocherType";
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
           {
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LedId",id);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment", "Payment");
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reciept", "Reciept");
               SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               if(dr.HasRows)
               {
                   while (dr.Read())
                   {
                     totalcredit = System.Convert.ToDecimal(dr["sum"].ToString());
                   }
               }
           }
           con.Close();
           con.Open();
           string sql1 = @"select sum(Amount) as sum,vocherType from Voucher where LedId=@LedId and vocherType=@Reciept group by vocherType";
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, con))
           {
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LedId", id);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment", "Payment");
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reciept", "Reciept");
               SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               if (dr.HasRows)
               {
                   while (dr.Read())
                   {
                       totaldebit = System.Convert.ToDecimal(dr["sum"].ToString());
                   }
               }
           }
           con.Close();
           if (totalcredit > totaldebit)
           {
               closingbalance = totalcredit - totaldebit;
               closingbalancetype = "credit";
           }
           else
           {
               closingbalance = totaldebit - totalcredit;
               closingbalancetype = "debit";
           }
           closingbalanceofledger.Add(closingbalancetype,closingbalance);
           return closingbalanceofledger;
        }
```

Comment: It depend if you want to print **all** dictionary (use **foreach**) or just one pair.

Comment: just one pair is it possible

Comment: What pair? You are not giving enough detail in your question.

Comment: _i have already a while so that i can reduce no of lines in my program_ ...No you cant. there is no problem with having nested loops. and there is no way to avoid that here.

Comment: @MosheD I edited question

Comment: Aside from anything else, I'd *strongly* advise you to start following .NET naming conventions.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is wrong in the sense that it relies on unspecified behavior; I quote `Dictionary` documentation:

> The order of the values in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated keys in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` returned by the Keys property.

This means that whatever `FirstOrDefault` returns is unspecified and can change depending on the current .NET framework, hardware, day of the week, number of observable sunspots in the sun, etc.

The only cases where the behavior of `Values.FirstOrDefault` will always be consistent is if the collection is empty or it has one single member; but if you are sure there is only one member then why are you using a dictionary in the first place? Nonetheless if it were the case, the correct option would be `Single()` which enforces that there must be only one member in the collection.

Now, if the case were that you wanted the first element of a collection which can have zero, one or more members, then this means that you must have some *ordering* criteria. Well then, *specify* it:

Is it by key?

```
var first = myDictionary.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is it some property of the value?

```
var first = myDictionary.OrderBy(kv => kv.Value.Foo).FirstOrDefault();
```

If the order you are interested in is the order in which the elements have been added to your collection then *do not use* a dictionary, use a `List` or, if you want to semantically make it clear, a `Queue`.

Comment: can I add more than 3 items in list

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionary contain ***only one*** value you can print

```
MessageBox.Show(d.FirstOrDefault().Key + " " + d.FirstOrDefault().Value);
```

Comment: this what i am looking for

Comment: @InBetween there is only one key value pair stored in dictionary